# Cannot write to /etc/hosts file from Dockerfile with RUN

Tags: docker, hosts-file

I am making a docker image using a pretty simple Dockerfile. Inside the Dockerfile I have this command:

```
RUN printf "192.92.13.243 www.hahaha.com \n" >> /etc/hosts
```

The command itself seems to be OK, since creation of the image does not halt at this point.

The issue is this: When running the image, the line that is supposed to have been inserted inside "/etc/hosts" is not there.

Now, I searched around and found out that before version 1.2 of docker, there was an issue with the hosts file inside the containers. In my case, I am using version 1.5, the latest as of this moment.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE 1:**

There seem  to be a lot of issues for this, both open and closed, in docker's github pages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After writing the update to my question I decided to take one more hard look at the "issues" opened in github. Turns out, a workaround has been implemented:

```
docker run ... --add-host='server:0.0.0.0' ...
```

Using the "--add-host..." argument when starting a container it is possible to modify the hosts file.

Comment: I want to be able to do this in build though. The person running the container shouldnt have to know about internal hosts. Makes zero sense!

Comment: I echo @samsamm777. Wonder if there is a good way of doing that?

Comment: This really is *very* surprising behaviour, which never is a good idea in IT systems.

Answer (score 12):

This works on docker 1.7.0

```
RUN echo "192.168.11.112 myhost" >> /etc/hosts && wget http://myhost
```

The trick is to add the hostname on the same line as you use it, otherwise the hosts file will get reset, since every RUN command starts a new intermediate container. For example, **this will not work**:

```
RUN echo "192.168.11.112 myhost" >> /etc/hosts
RUN wget http://myhost
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Although correct (I checked) and useful in general, it is of no real use to me in this case. I need the "hosts" file to be populated when the container runs.